# Event Bus is Listening but not Performing Action in Vue.JS

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm facing a problem on Event Bus. Not sure what problem it can be.

On Login(Component) Success:

```
LogIn(){
            Log.Success().then( user => {
            this.$router.replace('/')
            this.$eventBus.$emit('Sux');
            },  error => { 
                //Error
            });
        },
```

If Login Successful, User will be redirected to Home Page
On Homepage I am listening to Event:

```
data(){
   return{
      this.LogSuccess = false,
   }
}

created(){  

    this.$eventBus.$on('Sux', () => {
        this.LogSuccess = true
        alert(this.LogSuccess)
        console.log(this.LogSuccess)
    })
```

In console.log I'm seeing the `true` which is totally fine but data is not displaying

I'm expecting that LogSuccess becomes true and show data that is displayed only if LogSuccess condition is true.

But unfortunately it's not showing.

I'm trying to display Success message on Snackbar once the user signed in successfully.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Your emit is probably triggering well before the created hook of the other component is even run. Look into using Vuex for maintaining the users login state

Comment: I'm already maintaining Login state via Vuex. But I want to display Notification of Success login at once. Any take?

Comment: In created just check `if (this.$store.state.loginState === true) alert()`

Comment: @Robodude yeah that's work exactly, but on every Home page reload it shows alert. Don't you think it's a bad practice otherwise it's not a bad option.

Answer (score 0):

Try listening to event bus in mounted lifecycle event.

Comment: Alert() is showing True but still the data associated with True condition is not displaying. 
If I manually change the data it shows me

Comment: Can you create a sample in codesandbox and post here. There must be something weird going on.